# WordPress: How do i get a custom field value from custom taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy "News categories". This custom taxonomy has a custom text field "Category info".

How do I get the value of that field "Category info" within the post loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you saved the custom field in the options table, you could retrieve it like this:

```
$options = get_option( 'category_info' );
echo $options[$taxonomy->term_id];
```

Or if you are using ACF, you can retreive the custom field like this:

```
<?php

// load all 'category' terms for the post
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');


// we will use the first term to load ACF data from
if( !empty($terms) ) {

    $term = array_pop($terms);

    $custom_field = get_field('category_image', $term );

    // do something with $custom_field
}

?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure. I created the custom field with ACF plugin. I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If its created with ACF, you can retrieve it like this: 
     `<?php the_field('category_info', 'news'); ?>`

Comment: This doesn't work. I try to display the value of this custom field within the post loop - so if the post has a selected category, then that custom field of that custom taxonomy (category) is displayed.

Comment: Use the example in the ACF documentation labeled 'Finding the term related to the current post': https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/#examples\

Comment: Thank you Litzo, this did the job!